# MySQL max and MIN function showing 100 and above as minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

I made a query to show maximum and lowest value from database but it doesn't work perfectly. In cases where we have values from 100 and above it returns it lowest instead of 99 and below

```
SELECT MIN(total) AS min, MAX(total) AS max  FROM `results` WHERE `term_id` = 2 AND  `class_id` = 8 AND `subject_id` = 152
```

Result

```
min     max     
100     96
```

[image]

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `results` (
  `rst_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_test` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `second_test` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exam` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `term_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `session_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_new` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `is_upd` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_declared` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `declared_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: please provide the original table as create table and the data as text or fiddle. because i think you don't have a integer value you may have a char or varchar

Comment: Here is a link fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w19Edb3V9NNqSBuhtGWc3B/0

Comment: You are getting min and max of a varchar (total is varchar in your  fiddle and it should be integer). When you use varchar, 100 goes before (is lower) than 96, because 1 goes before 9, and the system uses alfabetical order, no numerical order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i thought you have a varchar and that is sorted by lexicographical order

use

```
SELECT MIN(total + 0) AS min, MAX(total + 0) AS max  
FROM `results` 
WHERE `term_id` = 2 AND  `class_id` = 8 AND `subject_id` = 152
```

this will convert it into a number